# WebSockts + Angular 5 + nodejs(express,Typescript) implementation

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I am using **Express Typescript Boilerplate** link "https://github.com/w3tecch/express-typescript-boilerplate" and angular 5 for client side

### Problem : i am trying to implement WebSockets for real time table data.

when i am on a specific page i need the WebSocket connection to be established and if i redirect to another page the connection should be closed.
The documentation for all the websocket implementations for node an angular totally focus on Chat single page applications.

> ```
>     /**
>      * We create a new Socket server instance.
>      */
>     const server = settings.getData('express_server');
>     //server is express app instance saved globally using 
>     //microframework-w3tec
>     let io = undefined;
>     if (io === undefined || io === null) {
>         console.log('socket loader initialized');
>         io = require('socket.io')();
>         io.on('connect', (socket: any) => {
>             console.log('a user connected');
>             io.emit('message', 'this is message');
>         });
>         io.listen(server);
>         io.on('add-message', (message) => {
>             io.emit('message', { type: 'new-message', text: message 
>      });
>         });
>         settings.setData('io', io);
> ```